# Android SQLite and string resources

Tags: android, sqlite

Can I store in DB string resource name, not value?

For example,`R.string.title, not "Some title"`. But when I want to using something like this:

```
 private static final String[] FROM = { Items.name };
 private static final int[] TO = { R.id.text1 };

 adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_list, null, FROM, TO, 0);
```

And in `R.id.text1` I want to see`"Item 3`" or, depends on current locale, `"Пункт 3" (in russian)`, not `"R.string.item3"`.

Comment: I think you are not calling [getString(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) at some point

Comment: Can you explain, please?

Comment: How do you assign `Items.name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And in R.id.text1 I want to see "Item 3" or, depends on current
>   locale, "Пункт 3" (in russian), not "R.string.item3".

Each column placed in `String[]` from will be assigned its value to `int[]` to in same order. In other words, every `Items.name` value will be assigned to `TextView` with `R.id.text1`

Comment: And there is no variant in this case is to get the value for the resource name from the database?

Comment: @none i think no, SimpleCursorAdapter is designated like this, into from array you are placing column you have to fetch and in to array you are adding ui elements which will be filled by values in from array.

Comment: Thanx. I will think further